# RegExp, replace the correct capitalised version of the keyword

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a simple text and when click button, i highlight a specific keyword.

```
<p id="mytext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
```

When i want to highlight **consectetur** and type **Consectetur**, it highlights but capitalize it.

But originally, it is not a capitalized word.

How can we fix it?

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/negav351/)**

```js
var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var word = "Consectetur";

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  mytext.innerHTML = mytext.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(word, 'gi'), '<span class="h">' + word + '</span>')

}, false);
```

```css
.h {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p id="mytext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Don't use `word` in the replacement, use a backreference instead.

Comment: Use a capturing group...

Comment: Capturing group? @brso05

Comment: `mytext.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("(" + word + ")", 'gi'), '<span class="h">$1</span>');`

Comment: But when we want to replace it,  we face the same problem? @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: Thanks, worked! @brso05

Comment: @Norx your welcome! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var word = /Consectetur/gi;

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  mytext.innerHTML = mytext.innerHTML.replace(word, '<span class="h">$&</span>')

}, false);
```

```css
.h {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p id="mytext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: You don't even have to create a capture, you can use `$&` that is a reference to the whole match.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: You're right, edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a capture group, and then replace with the matched value. `$1` references the first (and only) captured group.

```
mytext.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("(" + word + ")", 'gi'), '<span class="h">$1</span>')
```

```js
var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var word = "Consectetur";

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  mytext.innerHTML = mytext.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("(" + word + ")", 'gi'), '<span class="h">$1</span>')

}, false);
```

```css
.h {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p id="mytext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep you current code just append `.toLowerCase()` to `word`

ie:

```
word.toLowerCase()
```

```js
var mytext = document.getElementById("mytext");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var word = "Consectetur";

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  mytext.innerHTML = mytext.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(word, 'gi'), '<span class="h">' + word.toLowerCase() + '</span>')

}, false);
```

```css
.h {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p id="mytext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: This will only work with this case, what if he matches Consectetur, it will be lower cased when it shouldn't